# switching from one directory to another directory with same name different path in command line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

In Linux, I have two directories (just an example, this structure exist for every project checkout):

```
/root/user/<project>/<parent_directory>/<long path>/test
/root/user/<project>/<chidld_directory>/<long path>/test
```

How do I switch between both test directory easily without having to do long "cd ../../../..." command?

can I create command to switch between both test directories within the same project?

It's like aliasing,
detect current distance from project directory
then switch to child directory at same distance.

Comment: Make batch files with the proper names and paths and keep them in a special folder on your desktop. Then it will be easy to switch (and be correct).

Comment: Why not make use of aliases for both CD commands in your shell profile?

Answer (score 0):

If you're somewhere under the parent dir, you can

```sh
cd "${PWD/parent_dir/child_dir}"
```

If you're in a dir where the shell pattern `parent_dir` can't be found, you'll stay in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to jump between two directories you can use `cd -`. This requires you visit both directories first using `cd /path/to/test1` and then `cd /path/to/test2`.